# Reading UTF-16 file in java gives no data

Tags: java, utf-8, special-characters, utf-16

I am creating a csv file with data from the DB and encoding it to UTF-16LE to get the special characters like e`.But while I'm trying to read the same file in Java, as in:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
fileContent, "utf16"));
```

I am getting no data.

If I use UTF-8 encode while reading inputstream as in:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
fileContent, "utf8"));
```

using Buffered reader I'm getting all data but the special characters are coming as :

```
Brut¿l¿
```

where it should be Brutélé.

How do I get data in java with UTF-16? 
I have already tried with UTF-16LE and ANSI in my Java code. ANSI is giving unhandled exception, and 16LE is making no difference.

Below is the code to export the file:

`

```
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    final int BUFFER_SIZE =33554432;

    try {

        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));

        System.out.println("outStream = " + outStream);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        if (inputStream != null)
            try {
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    if (outStream != null)

                        outStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

Comment: have you tried to specify character set as `UTF-16` ?

Comment: Yes I have set charset name as utf-16 and utf-16le. Still getting no data.

Comment: Have you tried using `StandardCharsets`? That's a better way of accessing the charsets than string literals. Could you please post sample *bytes* of the file, as seen in a hex editor? Note that you don't need to use UTF-16 in order to store accented characters... UTF-8 is perfectly capable of that. Perhaps you should show the code you're using to write the file too...

Comment: Have you checked that `filecontent` contains the data in the right format? `Brutélé` in `UTF-16LE` represented as bytes is `42 00 72 00 75 00 74 00 E9 00 6C 00 E9 00`.

Comment: Java generally likes UTF-8 best.  Can your DB generate in that encoding?

Comment: `String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",fileName);
if (mimeType == null) {
mimeType = "application/octet-stream"
}response.setContentType(mimeType)
response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
outStream = response.getOutputStream()  inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes("UTF-16LE")
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]
int bytesRead = -1
if (inputStream != null)
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)`

Comment: Sorry about the jumbled up code @JonSkeet , but character limitations in the comment box forced my hand.

Comment: Nothing forced you to put the code in a comment - *edit your questoin*.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen exported CSV in UTF-8 is not recognising special characters. That is why I tried with UTF-16.

Comment: @JonSkeet added the code in the question.

Comment: @SubOptimal hexeditor shows the  data is in the right format. Brutélé shows up as:

42  72  75  74  E9  6C  E9

Comment: That's *not* UTF-16. That looks like it's actually ISO-8859-1.

Comment: It would really help if you'd remove the web aspect from this, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet edited the code further and removed the unnecessary parts. Will this suffice?

Comment: @RanitDholey Your output mechanism generating the file is most likely broken.  Investigate your file better.

Comment: Changing the output file format as in:
`
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileContent, "ISO-8859-1"));`

Solved the problem. Thanks a lot everyone :)

Comment: Well it's still not clear *why* you've got ISO-8859-1 data when you were trying to transmit it as UTF-16. I think you should put more time into understanding exactly what's going on. Note that ISO-8859-1 is still very limited in which characters is can represent.

Comment: I will definitely check and  get back to you if I figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As already said by [@John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). The byte sequence `42 72 75 74 E9 6C E9` is not UTF, it's ISO_8859_1.

You can verify it with following snippet

```
byte[] b = {0x42, 0x72, 0x75, 0x74, (byte) 0xE9, 0x6C, (byte) 0xe9};
System.out.println("ISO_8859_1: " 
        + new String(b, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
System.out.println("UTF_8     : " 
        + new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println("UTF_16LE  : " 
        + new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
```

output (on a Unicode aware console)

```
ISO_8859_1: Brutélé
UTF_8     : Brut�l�
UTF_16LE  : 牂瑵泩�
```

Comment: Changing the output file format as in: ` BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileContent, "ISO-8859-1"));` Solved the problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

You may use the unproper type of encoding.
Here are correct charset types [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)